# Making formulas in c# to convert dollar amount into denominations

Tags: c#

I'm making a program to convert any input amount into denominations of twenties, tens, fives, and ones. Here's what I'm having trouble with:

```
int twenties = dollar/20;
int tens = twenties/2;
int fives = tens/2;
int ones = fives/5;
```

Dollar is the input amount, the twenties expression seems to be the only one that comes out right. For example: I input 161 and it comes out as 161 is equal to 8 twenties, 4 tens, 2 fives, and 0 ones. But it should be coming out as 161 is equal to 8 twenties, 0 tens, 0 fives, and 1 ones. I know there is a really simple answer to this but I'm just not getting it, thanks guys.

Comment: You shouldn't divide the twenties by 2 but whatever amount is left after you took the twenties away.

Comment: How do you know that it should be 0 tens?

Comment: Because your title clearly says "C#", I changed your tags from "C" to "C#". Let me know if you do not agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work with the remainder after removing those denominations. The easiest way to get the remainder is the [modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator), like this...

```
int dollar = 161;
int twenties = dollar / 20;
int remainder = dollar % 20;
int tens = remainder / 10;
remainder = remainder % 10;
int fives = remainder / 5;
remainder = remainder % 5;
int ones = remainder;
```

The above approach does not modify the original amount. By refactoring that into a method, it makes it easier to reuse with different denominations:

```
public int RemoveDenomination(int denomination, ref int amount)
{
    int howMany = amount / denomination;
    amount = amount % denomination;
    return howMany;
}
```

...which you could use like this...

```
int dollar = 161;
int hundreds = RemoveDenomination(100, ref dollar);
int fifties = RemoveDenomination(50, ref dollar);
int twenties = RemoveDenomination(20, ref dollar);
int tens = RemoveDenomination(10, ref dollar);
int fives = RemoveDenomination(5, ref dollar);
int ones = dollar;
```

This approach *does* modify the `dollar` value. So if you don't want to change it, make a copy of it in another variable, and work on the copy.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the remainder and subtract until the remainder becomes 0;

```
int amount = 161, temp = 0;
int[] denomination = { 20, 10, 5, 1 }; // you can use enums also for 
// readbility
int[] count = new int[denomination.Length];

while (amount > 0)
{
    count[temp] = amount / denomination[temp];
    amount -= count[temp] * denomination[temp];
    temp ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use linq:

```
int[] denominations = new [] { 20, 10, 5, 1 };
List<int> result =
    denominations
        .Aggregate(new { Result = new List<int>(), Remainder = 161 }, (a, x) =>
        {
            a.Result.Add(a.Remainder / x);
            return new { a.Result, Remainder = a.Remainder % x };
        })
        .Result;
```

That returns a list with the values `{ 8, 0, 0, 1 }`.

---

Alternatively you could do this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> Denominations(int amount)
{
    var denominations = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    denominations["twenties"] = amount / 20;
    amount = amount % 20;

    denominations["tens"] = amount / 10;
    amount = amount % 10;

    denominations["fives"] = amount / 5;
    amount = amount % 5;

    denominations["ones"] = amount;

    return denominations;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This console app illustrates a possible solution:

```
internal static class Program
{
    internal static void Main()
    {
        var results = GetDenominationValues();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{result.Key} - {result.Value}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static Dictionary<int, int> GetDenominationValues()
    {
        var amount = 161;
        var denominations = new[] { 20, 10, 5, 1 };
        var results = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach (var denomination in denominations)
        {
            results.Add(denomination, amount / denomination);
            amount = amount % denomination;

            if (amount == 0) break;
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

The key difference is in the line:

```
amount = amount % denomination;
```

Which uses the remainder of the previous division in the subsequent calculations.

Answer (score -1):

If the division is greater than zero pass on the remainder (using the modulo operator, `%`) else pass on the original value to the next division in line. Repeat until no more division left.
Also, divide `tens` with 10, `fives` with 5 and `ones` with 1.

Answer (score -2):

Please use below function that returns dictionary

```
    public static Dictionary<string, int> Denominations(int amount)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> denominations = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "twenties", 0 }, { "tens", 0 }, { "fives", 0 }, { "ones", 0 } };

        int twenties, tens, fives, ones;
        if (amount >= 20)
        {
            twenties = amount/20;
            denominations["twenties"] = twenties;
            amount -= twenties * 20;
        }
        if (amount >= 10)
        {
            tens = amount/10;
            denominations["tens"] = tens;
            amount -= tens * 10;
        }
        if (amount >= 5)
        {
            fives = amount/5;
            denominations["fives"] = fives;
            amount -= fives * 5;
        }

        if (amount >= 1)
        {
            ones = amount;
            denominations["ones"] = ones;

        }

        return denominations;
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any mistake in the code, so vote down this code

Comment: Enigmativity, i just shared logic part only, as user posted his logic instead of entire code.

Comment: That's not the way this site works. You should always strive for working answers.

Comment: I like where you are going, but if I could down-vote it twice now I would. Why have the intermediate variables? And why `Convert.ToInt32(amount / 20)` and not just `amount / 20`? There's also no need for the `if`s.

Comment: Right , Convert.ToInt32 is not required.so i removed it

Answer (score -3):

You want Code number to text ?

```
MoneyExt mne = new MoneyExt();
string textamount;
textamount = mne.ConvertNumberToENG(10000);

using System;

public class MoneyExt
{
    public string ConvertNumberToENG(int amount)
    {
        var dollars, cents, temp;
        var decimalPlace, count;
        string[] place = new string[10];
        place[2] = " Thousand ";
        place[3] = " Million ";
        place[4] = " Billion ";
        place[5] = " Trillion ";

        // String representation of amount.
        amount = amount.Trim();
        amount = amount.Replace(",", "");
        // Position of decimal place 0 if none.
        decimalPlace = amount.IndexOf(".");
        // Convert cents and set string amount to dollar amount.
        if (decimalPlace > 0)
        {
            cents = GetTens(ref amount.Substring(decimalPlace + 1).PadRight(2, "0").Substring(0, 2));
            amount = amount.Substring(0, decimalPlace).Trim();
        }

        count = 1;
        while (amount != "")
        {
            temp = GetHundreds(amount.Substring(Math.Max(amount.Length, 3) - 3));
            if (temp != "")
                dollars = temp + place[count] + dollars;
            if (amount.Length > 3)
                amount = amount.Substring(0, amount.Length - 3);
            else
                amount = "";
            count = count + 1;
        }

        switch (dollars)
        {
            case "One":
                {
                    dollars = "One Bath";
                    break;
                }

            default:
                {
                    dollars = dollars + " Bath";
                    break;
                }
        }

        // Select Case cents
        // ' Case ""
        // '     cents = " and No Cents"
        // Case "One"
        // cents = " and One Satang"
        // Case Else
        // cents = " and " & cents & " Satang"
        // End Select

        ConvertNumberToENG = dollars + cents;
    }

    // Converts a number from 100-999 into text
    public string GetHundreds(string amount)
    {
        string Result;
        if (!int.Parse(amount) == 0)
        {
            amount = amount.PadLeft(3, "0");
            // Convert the hundreds place.
            if (amount.Substring(0, 1) != "0")
                Result = GetDigit(ref amount.Substring(0, 1)) + " Hundred ";
            // Convert the tens and ones place.
            if (amount.Substring(1, 1) != "0")
                Result = Result + GetTens(ref amount.Substring(1));
            else
                Result = Result + GetDigit(ref amount.Substring(2));
            GetHundreds = Result;
        }
    }

    // Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text.
    private string GetTens(ref string TensText)
    {
        string Result;
        Result = "";           // Null out the temporary function value.
        if (TensText.StartsWith("1"))
        {
            switch (int.Parse(TensText))
            {
                case 10:
                    {
                        Result = "Ten";
                        break;
                    }

                case 11:
                    {
                        Result = "Eleven";
                        break;
                    }

                case 12:
                    {
                        Result = "Twelve";
                        break;
                    }

                case 13:
                    {
                        Result = "Thirteen";
                        break;
                    }

                case 14:
                    {
                        Result = "Fourteen";
                        break;
                    }

                case 15:
                    {
                        Result = "Fifteen";
                        break;
                    }

                case 16:
                    {
                        Result = "Sixteen";
                        break;
                    }

                case 17:
                    {
                        Result = "Seventeen";
                        break;
                    }

                case 18:
                    {
                        Result = "Eighteen";
                        break;
                    }

                case 19:
                    {
                        Result = "Nineteen";
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (int.Parse(TensText.Substring(0, 1)))
            {
                case 2:
                    {
                        Result = "Twenty ";
                        break;
                    }

                case 3:
                    {
                        Result = "Thirty ";
                        break;
                    }

                case 4:
                    {
                        Result = "Forty ";
                        break;
                    }

                case 5:
                    {
                        Result = "Fifty ";
                        break;
                    }

                case 6:
                    {
                        Result = "Sixty ";
                        break;
                    }

                case 7:
                    {
                        Result = "Seventy ";
                        break;
                    }

                case 8:
                    {
                        Result = "Eighty ";
                        break;
                    }

                case 9:
                    {
                        Result = "Ninety ";
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
            }
            Result = Result + GetDigit(ref TensText.Substring(1, 1));  // Retrieve ones place.
        }
        GetTens = Result;
    }

    // Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text.
    private string GetDigit(ref string Digit)
    {
        switch (int.Parse(Digit))
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    GetDigit = "One";
                    break;
                }

            case 2:
                {
                    GetDigit = "Two";
                    break;
                }

            case 3:
                {
                    GetDigit = "Three";
                    break;
                }

            case 4:
                {
                    GetDigit = "Four";
                    break;
                }

            case 5:
                {
                    GetDigit = "Five";
                    break;
                }

            case 6:
                {
                    GetDigit = "Six";
                    break;
                }

            case 7:
                {
                    GetDigit = "Seven";
                    break;
                }

            case 8:
                {
                    GetDigit = "Eight";
                    break;
                }

            case 9:
                {
                    GetDigit = "Nine";
                    break;
                }

            default:
                {
                    GetDigit = "";
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: "You want Code number to text ?" - No, they want to break down an amount into the notes and coins.